# How to prompt Date and Time and then alert with that date and time minus 40 minutes

Tags: javascript, date

I am doing work for a class and the question is asking us to prompt the user for their flight departure date, then the next prompt asks the user to enter the departure time, and then we need an alert telling them the last possible time of check-in (40 minutes before).

I've got the prompts and alert to work but I am struggling to find a way to minus the 40 minutes. I have tried using the get function but I don't know if it's incorrect or if I'm doing it wrong.

```js
var day = prompt("When is your departure date? (eg. 2019-10-12):", "2019-10-12");

var tim = prompt("When is your departure time? (eg. 10:30):", "10:30");

var time = tim - 40;
var check = alert("The check in counter closes:" + day + " " + time);
```

I know that the time should show as 40 minutes before but If the flight leaves at 00:30 I don't know how to make it use the previous date and 23:50.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new `Date()` object with the first prompt return, then set hour and minute of this object with the second prompt value.

Then compute the time difference like so :

```
let diff_ms = Date.now() - (new Date(<promptvalue...>).now());
```

and check if the diff is under 40 mn assuming diff is in ms :

```
let fortyMn_ms = 1000 * 60 * 40;
if(diff_ms < fortyMn_ms) { /*... */ }
```

Comment: To work correctly, the *promptvalue* will need to be a format supported by ECMA-262, e.g. 2019-10-05T12:23:43+05:30.

Answer (score -1):

Convert your strings to a `Date()` and then do: `date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() - 40)` and convert back to a string to print.

Example:

```js
var day = prompt("When is your departure date? (eg. 2019-10-12):", "2019-10-12");

var tim = prompt("When is your departure time? (eg. 10:30):", "10:30");

let date = new Date(day + 'T' + tim);
date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() - 40);

let formatted_date = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear() + " " + date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes();

var check = alert("The check in counter closes: " + formatted_date);
```

Comment: This worked beautifully. It makes total sense now that I've seen what it's supposed to be. Thank you!!

Comment: @JAnneON Your welcome, glad it helped. If this response resolved your problem please mark with a check mark so others know it's answered.

Comment: Don't use the built–in parser for unsupported string formats, parsing of `new Date('2019-10-12 10:30')` is implementation dependent and returns an invalid date in at least one popular browser.

Comment: @RobG What do you suggest so I can enhance the response?